# Error NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED when calculating a route

Tags: here-api

When I calculate the route from coordinate 49.4935,0.5118 to 41.8114,2.7408 (truck + trailer 40ton) the web service returns error 400 - Bad request.
I have tested this with the example https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api, and this explains the reason: the second waypoint is in a zone with a restriction of 7.5 ton (see image).
Is there a possibility to get this error from the webservice, so I can alert the user what the problem is?

[Here example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra2Rf.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you make your request, you get this response:

```
{
    "issues": [
        {
            "message": "Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links 907492075 -907492075 907492077 -907492077 907493126 -907493126  dest links 719515104 -719515104 ), link 907492075 might restrict access for the vehicle type, link 907492075's through traffic restriction might apply, link 907492077 might restrict access for the vehicle type, link 907492077's through traffic restriction might apply, link 907493126's through traffic restriction might apply"
        },
        {
            "message": "Request id: bfb4932d-f159-4d3a-986e-77f6bc41b143"
        }
    ],
    "response": null,
    "error_id": "bfb4932d-f159-4d3a-986e-77f6bc41b143",
    "response_code": "400 Bad Request"
}
```

The response code is `400 Bad Request` but there is also a list of messages in `issues` that you can use to alert the user.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get these issues when asking for toll costs. If I add &rollup=none,country;tollsys,total to my URL I get the error NGEO_ERROR_GRAPH_DISCONNECTED